# Can I convert color attribute to mask?

Tags: masking, vertex-colors, conversion

Good day. I need to adapt blender material to UE5, but this engine doesn't support color attributes, so I need to replace it with texture mask. Can I convert these color attributes to masks? Blender's version 4.0.2

Comment: You can bake the Vertex Paint onto an Image Texture if this is what you are looking for?

Comment: @moonboots maybe, I just don't know what exactly I'm looking for. How can I do that?

Comment: this is weird, I'm pretty sure UE5 supports vertex colors https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.26/en-US/BuildingWorlds/LevelEditor/Modes/MeshPaintMode/VertexColor/MaterialSetup/Color/

Comment: @Alex oh, yes, you're right. Maybe I missed something, but if I have `colormap1` and `colormap2` I can't get access to one of them. Need a little more time to find out, and I will happy if it's working with layers, but for now only moonboots solution is working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If UE5 doesn't support vertex colors (?), you can bake them onto an *Image Texture*. First thing unwrap your object, create an *Image Texture* node in the *Shader Editor*, give it a new image, keep it selected if you ever have several *Image Texture* nodes in your material, create an *Input > Attributes > Attribute* node, plug it into the *Output* node. In the *Render* panel switch to Cycles render engine and under *Bake* choose *Type > Emit*, click on *Bake*:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it should be Emit? I've seen people using diffuse > Influence: color > Output: Active color attribute. Will I get different result in this case?

Comment: It should not make any difference